# Create an association through a single form Mongoose/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

Through a single form I'm trying to build a game object that consists of a 'game_name', and a 'game_length', and a ref association by ObjectId to a 'player'. What I have is building both objects but the player is not being saved in the players array in the Game model. Thanks for any help in advance.

### Schema and Models

Game Schema/Model

```
var gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  course_name: String,
  game_length: Number,
  players: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Game'
  }],
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})
var Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);
```

Player Schema/Model

```
var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  player_name: String,
})
var Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);
```

### Post Route

```
app.post('/games', function(req, res){
Game.create(req.body.game, function(err, newGame){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      Player.create(req.body.player, function(err, newPlayer){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        newGame.players.push(newPlayer);
      })
      res.redirect('games');
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to call `.save`:

```
app.post('/games', function(req, res){
Game.create(req.body.game, function(err, newGame){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      Player.create(req.body.player, function(err, newPlayer){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        newGame.players.push(newPlayer);
        newGame.save(function(err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          // saved!
          res.redirect('games');
        });
      })
   })
})
```